# Specific command to change server type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the command, if there is any, to change the server type I use for rails?

My default is Thin which works great. When I need to change to webrick, is there something like

```
rails s server=webrick
```

I don't want my default setting to be changed though. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
rails s thin additional options
```

Or equivalent for whatever server type you want to use

Comment: Too simple. I tried rails s webrick and it changed to webrick. I tried to overcomplicate things :) Thanks.